# Allocation problems and weird behavior in C

Tags: c, out-of-memory, allocation

Hy!
I have some problems with this code, because it works on my laptop (win 10), but when i have tried it on an older computer (with win 7), it crashes everytime. Also, sometimes, it fails to reallocate memory if I have more files, but not only (for example, it works with 12 files, but on 13th file, it crashes).
SO NOW this is the modified code and now it works properly on win 7, but not on win 10, it's like the problem has inverted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   FILE *f, *fc;
   float lg, lt;
   int q, l, i, n;
   char lgs[20], lts[20], qs[5], *s, *t, *sir2="</parts></data>", *sir1="<? 
   xml version=\"1.0\"?><data><parts>";
   char *ch, sl[100], numeI[20], numeO[20], *sir="text with 3 space pattern", 
   *sir3="some long text";
   printf("INTRODU NUMARUL DE FISIERE: ");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
        if(i<10) sprintf(numeI, "0000000%d.###", i);
            else sprintf(numeI, "000000%d.###", i);

        f=fopen(numeI, "r");
        if(f==NULL)
       {
            perror("Eroare deschidere fisier");
            return(1);
       }
       sprintf(numeO, "optimizare%d.xml", i);

       fc=fopen(numeO, "w");
       if(fc==NULL)
       {
           perror("Eroare deschidere fisier");
           return(1);
       }

       l=strlen(sir)+strlen(sir3);
       s=(char*) malloc((strlen(sir1)+l+1));
       strcpy(s, sir1);
       fgets(sl, 100, f);

       while(fgets(sl, 100, f))
       {
           strcat(s, sir);
           sscanf(sl, "%f %f %d", &lg, &lt, &q);
           lg=lg*10;
           lt=lt*10;
           sprintf(lgs, "%.2f", lg);
           sprintf(lts, "%.2f", lt);
           sprintf(qs, "%d", q);
           ch=strstr(s, "        ");
           if(ch==NULL)
           {
               perror("EROARE CH 1");
           }
           strncpy(ch, lgs, strlen(lgs));

           ch=strstr(s, "        ");
           if(ch==NULL)
           {
               perror("EROARE CH 2");
           }
           strncpy(ch, lts, strlen(lts));

           ch=strstr(s, "        ");
           if(ch==NULL)
           {
               perror("EROARE CH 3");
           }
           strncpy(ch, qs, strlen(qs));

           t=(char*) realloc(s, (strlen(s)+l+25));
           if(t==NULL) {
                           perror("\nEROARE REALOCARE");
                           return 1;
                       }
           s=t;
           strcat(s, sir3);
        }

    t=(char*) realloc(s, (strlen(s)+strlen(sir2)));
    if(t==NULL) {
                    perror("\nEROARE REALOCARE 2");
                    return 1;
                }
    s=t;
    strcat(s, sir2);
    fprintf(fc, s);
    fclose(f);
    fclose(fc);
}
printf("CONVERTIRE EFECTUATA");
```

}
Do you know where is the problem ?

Comment: Have you made any attempts at debugging where it fails?

Comment: start by checking the return values of library functions.

Comment: It's very awkward. When I debug, it works for all files (example 13 files), but when not, it work only for first 10 files, then i get REALLOCATION ERROR: not enough space.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* 3) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation function: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`: 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful. 2) when calling `realloc`, always assign the returned value to a 'temp' variable, test the variable for success and only if successfu, assigned the value to the target pointer.  Otherwise, when the  call to `realloc` fails, the original pointer is overlayed with a NULL value, resulting a unrecoverable memory leak

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu17` )  The posted code causes the compiler to output several warnings.

Comment: the returned value from the heap allocation functions has type `void*`, which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: regarding: `=(char*) realloc(s, (strlen(s)+strlen(sir2))*sizeof(char));`  the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has absolutely no effect (other than cluttering the code)  strongly suggest removing that expression

Comment: OT:  The posted code contains some `magic` numbers.  `magic` numbers are numbers with no basis.  Like 100.  Suggest using `#define` statements or a `enum` statement to give those `magic` numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: regarding: `f=fopen(numeI, "r");
  sprintf(numeO, "optimizare%d.xml", i);
  fc=fopen(numeO, "w");
  
  if(f==NULL)
  {
   perror("Eroare deschidere fisier");
   return(1);
  }
  
  if(fc==NULL)
  {
   perror("Eroare deschidere fisier");
   return(1);
  }`  Any call to `perror()` must be immediately after the statement that caused the problem.  otherwise, some other statement will have modified `errno` so `perror()` will not output the correct error message

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: it is poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not being used.  Suggest removing the statement: `#include <ctype.h>`

Comment: variable names should indicate `content` or `usage`.  names like `q` `l` `i` `n` `s` `sir2`, etc are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: I modified some code (see below comment) and now works on win 7, but if i copy-paste on a win 10 computer, it doesn't work for all files (it's the first problem, but inverted now)

Comment: regarding: `if(fc==NULL)
  {
   perror("Eroare deschidere fisier");
   return(1);
  }`  and similar code blocks:  the code should also be passing the allocated memory pointers to `free()`.  it is poor programming practice to have the OS cleanup after sloppy code

Comment: regarding: `l = strlen(sir);
  s = malloc( (strlen(sir1)+l+1) );`  this is an odd way to say: `s = malloc( 2* strlen( sir1 ) +1 );`

Comment: regarding: `fgets(sl, 100, f);
  
  while(fgets(sl, 100, f))` this will overlay the first line of input.  Is that what you really want to do?

Comment: the array `qs[]` is only 5 characters long.  if the value entered (by the user) is more than 4 characters long,  I.E. longer than `99.9` then the buffer will be overflowed, resulting in undefined behavior.  Sadly, the code does not check for such things

Comment: Yep, this is want i want to do regarding fgets(). Regarding qs[], i don't need at all a longer space.

Comment: regarding: `char *ch,`  this allocates a pointer, but does not point it at any (application owned) memory.  Then this: `ch=strstr(s, "        ");` is nonsense .  And this: `strncpy(ch, lgs, strlen(lgs));` will be writing to some unknown area in memory, resulting in undefined behavior (and probably result in a seg fault event)

Comment: this kind of statement: `fgets(sl, 100, f);` will make code modifications difficult.  Suggest using: `fgets(sl, sizeof( sl ), f);`

Comment: regarding: `lg=lg*10;
   lt=lt*10;`  the `lg` and `lt` are `float` variables, so why are then being multiplied by an `integer` rather than a `float`?

Comment: Regarding to initialization of *ch, where should i point it ? To s ? And why is ch=strstr(s, " "); nonsense ? Does it not make ch to point to first apparition of "   " in s ?

Comment: the function: `realloc()` does NOT clear the additional allocated memory to `spaces`  The code needs to do that,   Since the 8 spaces will not be found, the statement: `ch=strstr(s, "        ");` will set the pointer `ch` to NULL,  Then the statement: `strncpy(ch, qs, strlen(qs));` will be (trying) to write to address 0 (which is undefined behavior and can/should lead to a seg fault event

Comment: regarding your statement: `then i get REALLOCATION ERROR: not enough space`  this is because the code is writing beyond the end of the allocated memory, thereby corrupting the heap formatting.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised this works on any platform.

Look at these two lines:

```
    ch=strstr(s, "        ");
    strncpy(ch, lgs, strlen(lgs));
```

So you search for `"        "` in the string `s` and (without checking for NULL) simply copies some other string to the location.

But if `s` doesn't contain the `"        "` pattern, `ch` will be NULL and the program will crash on the copy operation.

So do `s` contain the pattern?

I don't think so!

How is `s` constructed the very first time?

```
strcpy(s, sir1);                // Copy of sir1
fgets(sl, 100, f);
while(fgets(sl, 100, f))
{
    strcat(s, sir);            // Append of sir
```

Since `sir1` and `sir` doesn't contain the pattern neither will `s` and `ch` will be NULL.

**Advice**

Always check return values!

**Example**

```
    ch = strstr(s, "        ");
    if (ch == NULL)
    {
        // Add error handling here
    }
    strncpy(ch, lgs, strlen(lgs));
```

This goes for all other library calls as well (e.g. `malloc`)

Comment: The pattern is in sir1, but it was too long the text to put it here.

Comment: @Robert that's why for debugging-help, you are asked to create a [mcve]

Comment: I checked now returned values for ch, but isn't any error.

Comment: So, I succeeded to make it to work. I split the long text from sir1 in 2 strings, one with the patterns and the another one with the rest of the text, which i join to s at the end of the while through strcat. Thanks for your attention !

Comment: Or not...it works on win 7, but not on win 10. It say it haven't enough space for reallocation..